# Filtrar un Outputtext jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Quisiera saber como filtrar para que solo me aparezcan las patentes de vehiculos que esten disponibles.

```
<p:column headerText="Patente Auto"                   
    <h:outputText value="#{v.fkVehiculo.patente}"/>               
</p:column>
```

En la base de datos hay una tabla que se llama Estado con 2 ingresos

`id_estado 1    ---- nombre_estado Disponible` y `id_estado 2 ---- nombre_estado No disponible`

Lo que requiero es que solo se muestren las patentes de los vehiculos que tengan el 'Estado' en 'Disponible'

La tabla Estado tiene su respectivo Bean

Espero que puedan ayudarme

Codigo de ingreso Alquiler

```
<h:head>
    <title>Realizar Alquiler</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>Realizar Alquiler</h2>
    <h:form id="fv">

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="panelGridCenter">

        <h:outputText value="Precio"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{alquilerBean.precio}" required="true"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="datetime" value="Fecha" />
        <p:calendar id="datetime" value="#{alquilerBean.fecha3}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" required="true"/>

        Cliente
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{alquilerBean.cliente.idCliente}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{clienteBean.cliente}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.rut}" itemValue="#{e.idCliente}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        Patente
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{alquilerBean.vehiculo.idVehiculo}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{vehiculoBean.vehiculos}" var="o" itemLabel="#{o.patente}" itemValue="#{o.idVehiculo}"/>   
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        ¿Entregado?
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{alquilerBean.entregado.idEntregado}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{entregadoBean.entregado}" var="o" itemLabel="#{o.nombreEntregado}" itemValue="#{o.idEntregado}"/>   
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <br/>
        <h:outputText value=""/>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{alquilerBean.crear()}" value="Agregar Alquiler" update="fv"/>

        </h:panelGrid> 
        <br/>
        <p:dataTable value="#{alquilerBean.alquiler}" var="v" emptyMessage="No hay registros" >


            <p:column headerText="Fecha">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.fecha}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Precio">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.precio}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Entregado">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.fkEntregado.nombreEntregado}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Rut Cliente">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.fkCliente.rut}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Patente Auto"

                <h:outputText value="#{v.fkVehiculo.patente}"/>   

            </p:column>

            </p:column>

             <f:facet name="footer">
                 Se han alquilado #{alquilerBean.alquiler.size()} Vehiculos.
            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>    
    <br/>
    <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="index">
    <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/atras2.png" />
    </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>


</h:body>
</html>
```

Aca esta el codigo del bean de estado.

```
private int id_entregado;
private String nombre_entregado;


public EntregadoBean() {
}

public String crear(){
    Entregado e = new Entregado();
    e.setNombreEntregado(nombre_entregado);
    entregadoFacade.create(e);
    return "#";
}

public List<Entregado> getEntregado(){
    return entregadoFacade.findAll();
}

public EntregadoFacadeLocal getEntregadoFacade() {
    return entregadoFacade;
}

public void setEntregadoFacade(EntregadoFacadeLocal entregadoFacade) {
    this.entregadoFacade = entregadoFacade;
}

public int getId_entregado() {
    return id_entregado;
}

public void setId_entregado(int id_entregado) {
    this.id_entregado = id_entregado;
}

public String getNombre_entregado() {
    return nombre_entregado;
}

public void setNombre_entregado(String nombre_entregado) {
    this.nombre_entregado = nombre_entregado;
}

}
```

Comment: id estado 1 nombre_estado disponible

Comment: id_estado 2 nombre_estado no disponible

Comment: es una aplicacion de alquiler de autos la cual en esa pestaña se alquila el auto

Answer (score 0):

Si posteas más código es más fácil ayudarte.

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```
<p:column headerText="Entregado">
                <h:outputText value="#{v.fkEntregado.nombreEntregado=='Disponible'? v.fkEntregado.nombreEntregado : ''} "/>
            </p:column>
```

Comment: Ya subi el codigo de ingresar alquiler, cualquier consulta me dices. Gracias por responder

Comment: Igualmente subí el bean de estado

Comment: Pudiste llegar a algo :c?

Comment: Pero no esta mostrando las patentes de autos filtrados. El filtro ni iría en el headerText de autos?